# How to get parameters from a quadratic fit in Stata?

Tags: stata, fitting

Using the Stata `graph twoway` command, I have created a scatterplot with a quadratic best fit line, using the `qfit` command.  How can I get the equation of the best fit line?

Example:

```
graph tw (scatter y x) (qfit y x)
```

Comment: You should include your specific code to make it easier for people to give an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your graph, using auto as an example.

```
sysuse auto, clear
graph tw (scatter  price mpg) (qfit  price mpg), name(graph1)
```

regress y on x and x^2  and get predicted values (see`help fvvarlist` if you don't know about this notation)

```
regress price mpg c.mpg#c.mpg
```

The output from `regress` gives you the "equation" of the fitted line (y=b1*x + b2*x*x + b3) and the following graph is equivalent:

```
predict fitted
sort mpg
graph tw (scatter  price mpg) (line fitted mpg) , name(graph2)
```

Answer (score 2):

`qfit` is a convenience command that simply calls `regress`, then obtains and plots the predicted values. So if you want the fit parameters, you can call `regress` yourself.